# ACCESS_VIOLATION_BAD_IP

Tags: debugging, crash, windbg

I am trying to figure out a crash in my application. 
WinDbg tells me the following: (using dashes in place of underscores)

**LAST-CONTROL-TRANSFER:  from 005f5c7e to 6e697474

DEFAULT-BUCKET-ID:  BAD_IP

BUGCHECK-STR: ACCESS-VIOLATION**

It is obvious to me that 6e697474 is NOT a valid address.

I have three questions:

1) Does the "BAD_IP" bucket ID mean "Bad Instruction Pointer?"

2) This is a multi-threaded application so one consideration was that the object whose function I was attempting to call went out of scope. Does anyone know if that would lead to the same error message?

3) What else might cause an error like this? One of my co-workers suggested that it might be a **stack overflow** issue, but WinDBG in the past has proven rather reliable at detecting and pointing these out. (not that I'm sure about the voodoo it does in the background to diagnose that).

Answer (score 2):

Bad-IP is Bad Instruction Pointer. From the description of your problem, I would assume it is a **stack corruption** instead of a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following things that could cause a jump to invalid address, in decreasing order of likelyhood:

- calling a member function on a deallocated object. (as you suspect)
- calling a member function of a corrupted object.
- calling a member function of an object with a corrupted vtable.
- a rouge pointer overwriting code space.

I'd start debugging by finding the code at 005f5c7e and looking at what objects are being accessed around there.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to ask, what could have written the string 'ttie' to this location? Often when you have bytes in the 0x41-0x5A, 0x61-0x7A ([a-zA-Z]) range, it indicates a string buffer overflow.

As to what was actually overwritten, it could be the return address, some other function pointer you're using, or occasionally that a virtual function table pointer (`vfptr`) in an object got overwritten to point to the middle of a string.